# Prove that if A has eigenvalues then determinant of A is the product of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that if A has eigenvalues then determinant of A is the product of its eigenvalues?

Comment: Look at your the constant in the characteristic polynomial and use the relation between roots of equation and product of roots.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) Jordan Canonical Form

2) $\textrm{det}(AB) = \textrm{det}(A)\textrm{det}(B)$

Comment: Can you write a full proof ? @BaronVT